# Hide specific cells in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to hide specific cells in gridview. I have a view that is generated that has a delete column. I want the delete column there so I cant hide the entire thing using:

```
Gridview.Columns[3].Visible = false;
```

But if the row was generated before a certain date I don't want the delete cell to show up in that row. I already have the logic to check this but how do I hide the actual specific cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign empty string to cell, you can not hide single cell with server code.

```
Gridview.Rows[3].Cell[index].Text = "";
```

OR, clear all controls in the cell.

```
Gridview.Rows[3].Cell[index].Controls.Clear();
```

Comment: You can just store the contents of the cell in anther value, and just add the text back in when you want to show it

Answer (score 1):

Add some logic into the `GridView`'s `RowDataBound` event handler to make the cell's content visible or not.

A Good example on [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hide the cell.  Just make the content **invisible**.

So, you could set the content to an **empty string**, or you could set the `IsVisible` (or similar) property on whatever control you may have in the cell.